# Resize my chart based on my xAxis text with d3.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm trying to resize my chart based on my axis texts, using d3.js in a node server. But i'm getting some errors and nuable values, this is the list of tries to get the axis dimensions to set the innerHeight correctly:

```
With: getBoundingClientRect()
Code: g.select('.axis-content').node()?.getBoundingClientRect()
Result: { bottom: 0, height: 0, left: 0, right: 0, top: 0, width: 0 }
```

```
With: getComputedTextLength()
Code: g.select('.axis-content').node()?.getComputedTextLength()
Result: getComputedTextLength() is not a function
```

```
With: preserveAspectRatio and viewbox
Result: No effect
```

I think I have to set dynamically the margin bottom adding the height of the xAxis to it, because the text can change based on the country name.

So, how can I solve this problem, and resize my chart based on the tick text? Seens to me that xAxis is created but haven't the width or height, and only when i start the inspect mode on google chrome, this values comes up, but they are not at the element.

My code is here: [Github Gist - chart.ts](https://gist.github.com/AlexandreMacedoo/e23a3630cbf9b7f84048ceb86e4f3b59)

This is my chart normal / resized:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a thread that discusses this.](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1590)

Looks like you might be able to make it happen with this function:

```
const p = document.createElement('p')

    p.getBoundingClientRect = jest.fn(() => ({
      x: 851.671875,
      y: 200.046875,
      width: 8.34375,
      height: 17,
      top: 967.046875,
      right: 860.015625,
      bottom: 984.046875,
      left: 851.671875,
    }))
```

I've run into this before using documentFragment. Another possible workaround is you could estimate the size based on the number of characters in the text and possibly look into using a fixed-width font to help with accuracy.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the point, it seems to me that I can't get the dimensions of my element, because the jsdom creates the elements without width and height if i didn't specify it. How could I implement this code using node?

Comment: Thank you, Im measuring the text with canvas